# Find the image of a set under a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

I have the function $$f(z) = \frac{z-1}{z+1}$$ and I have to find the image of the set
$$D= \{ z\in \mathbb C | \operatorname{Re} z<0 \text{ and } \operatorname{Im} z<0\}$$
And it's given that $f(-1)=\infty$ and $f(\infty) = 1$.

I started by writing $z = x + yi$ and I plugged it into the function, the result is:$$ f(z) = \frac{x^2+y^2-1}{(x+1)^2+y^2} + \frac{2yi}{(x+1)^2+y^2} $$

and i realized that all the points will have the image in the 4th quadrant except those that are in the unit circle and inside D and those would have the image between -1 and 1 with y < 0. So the image will be all the points with $x\in(-1, \infty)$ and $y < 0$.

Am I right?

Comment: You mapping is a Möbius transformation which maps circles into circles (where lines are regarded as circles).  More specifically, Möbius transforms work as rotations on the Riemann sphere. Does this help you? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation) any Mobius transformation $f(z) = \frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ could be represented as a composition of four simple transformations (here we have $a=1, b=-1, c=1, d=1$)

- $f_1(z) = z + \frac{d}{c}$, i.e. translation by $\frac{d}{c}$ of the plane.
- $f_2(z) = \frac{1}{z}$, i.e. inversion of the plane
- $f_3(z) = \frac{bc-ad}{c^2}z$, i.e. rotation, then scaling
- $f_4(z) = z + \frac{a}{c}$, another translation

in our case

- $f_1(z) = z + 1$
- $f_2(z) = \frac{1}{z}$
- $f_3(z) = -2z$
- $f_4(z) = z + 1$

[image: forth quadrant depicted]
[image: first translation by 1]

The interesting part is to understand, how $\frac{1}{z}$ deforms the "translated quadrant". Basically, the inversion is first invert with respect to the unit circle, than reflect with respect to Real axis. Inside of the unit circle $D$ becomes the plane except $D$.

[image: Plane colored before the inversion with respect to the unit circle]
[image: Plane colored after the inversion with respect to the unit circle]

See how the inside of the unit circle got inverted with respect to the unit circle!

The line $1 + i\cdot t$ (the line containing the right boundary) is transformed into the circle that passes through $f_2(1) = 1$, $f_2(\infty) = 0$ and $f_2(1-i) = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}i$ -i.e. the circle centered at $(0, \frac{1}{2})$ with radius $\frac{1}{2}$. Check out the anything with $Re(z) > 1$ is outside the unit circle, hence is sent to the inside, i.e. the circle above is not the image of $D$ under $f_2 \circ f_1$.

[image: The right part before the inversion]
[image: is sent into the smaller disk]

And the real line is preserved.
Overall, after the final reflection with respect to the Real axis, we have the next image

[image: inversion]

$f_3$ - rotates the plane by $\pi$, this is the multiplication by $-1$,

[image: rotation by \pi]

then scales everything by $2$, i.e. the image is now $Im(z) < 0$, except the circle centered at $(-1,0)$ with radius $1$.

[image: scaling by 2]

And $f_4$ then translates everything by $1$.

[image: translation by 1]

All in all, $f(D) = \{z\; |\; Im(z) <0 \} \setminus D$

Comment: How does the 1/z transform the plane with Re(z)<1 and Im(z)< 0 into Im(z) > 0 without the circle (1/2, 0) with radius of 1/2?

Comment: $Im(z) < 0$ is transformed into $Im(z) > 0$. Inversions with respect to unit circle preserves the "sidedness", then you reflect with respect to Real axis.

Comment: Why it is with respect to unit circle?

Comment: I'm trying to follow your steps but i end up in Im(z) > 0 with Re(z) > 2  .. and the problem is with that inversion

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversive_geometry#Circle_inversion for first invertsion with respect to the unit circle (i.e. $2$ is mapped for example to $\frac{1}{2}$ and $3i$ to $\frac{1}{3}i$). In other words the inside of the unit circle is mapped to the outside and vice versa (but the sidedness is preserved). (Then you reflect about Real axis). After that the question is what is the image of the $Re(z) > 1$ - this is mapped into the small circle.

Comment: I've added more images that depicts the inversion with regard to quadrants and the line, but without the final reflection

Answer (score 0):

The mapping $f$ takes the negative imaginary axis to the unit semi-circle below the real axis and takes the negative real axis to the two segments on the real line: $x>1$ and $x<1$.  We now have the boundary for the mapping.  Take a point in the interior of $\cal{D}$, for example $p=-1-i$.  $f(p)= 1-2i$ which is below the boundary.  Thus, $f$ maps $\cal{D}$ below the boundary.

Since the boundary of $\cal{D}$ is not included in the domain, the image of the boundary of $\cal{D}$ is not included in the range of $f(\cal{D})$.

Answer (score 0):

Given that $Re(z)<0$ and $Im(z)<0$, we can deduce follows successively,

$$Re(z+1)<1,\>\>\>\>\>Im(z+1)<0$$
$$Re(\frac1{z+1})<1 ,\>\>\>\>\> Im(\frac1{z+1})>0$$
$$Re(\frac2{z+1})<2 ,\>\>\>\>\> Im(\frac2{z+1})>0$$
$$Re(-\frac2{z+1})>-2 ,\>\>\>\>\> Im(-\frac2{z+1})<0$$
$$Re(1-\frac2{z+1})>-1 ,\>\>\>\>\> Im(1-\frac2{z+1})<0$$

Recognizing $f(z) = \frac{z-1}{z+1}=1- \frac2{z+1}$, we have the image $Re f(z) >-1$ and $Im f(z) <0$.

Comment: $\Im (z+1) <1$.

Comment: $f(\frac{-1-i}{2})=-1-2i.$

Comment: shouldn't it be  Re(z+1) < 1 to Re(1/(z+1)) > 1 and Im(1/(z+1)) < 0 => Im(-2/(z+1)) > 0 => Im(1 - 2/(z+1)) > 1 ?